# GeoJSON load Properly in QGIS but not in GeoJSON viewer

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file. It loads properly in QGIS but not in JSON viewer (http://geojson.io). I have select EPSG:4326 as the CRS.

When I open the GeoJSON file in notepad++ and check the coordinates they look like 
*"coordinates": [ [ [ [ 735162.3406, 1403154.0408 ]...."*

I think these are not valid.

Let me explain briefly:

Snapshot: When GeoJSON file load in QGIS - 
[image: when GeoJSON load in QGIS]

Snapshot: When same GeoJSON file load in geojson.io

[image]

GeoJSON file link - https://drive.google.com/open?id=15iuoKcyHPU7rsJ6VtHMT7ojhKAfHU057

Comment: That is not EPSG:4326 coordinates. When you export from QGIS to geojson select EPSG 4326.

Comment: @Anton vBR you should submit that as an answer - it's totally valid, doesn't matter it's short - it will improve the tally of unanswered questions which = bad

Comment: Thanks for the review it... I have update the question with more description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

---

**Short answer:** Those are not EPSG:4326 coordinates.

---

**Long answer** (and possible workaround):

I downloaded your file and posted it on geojsonlint.com. Which resulted in:

[image]

Ok, so you say you can import this to QGIS and it displays? This is most likely due to the fact QGIS can validate and correct GEOJSON. The GEOJSON-lint indicated we have an old-style crs member.

Ok, looking at your coordinates you have most likely the Pseudo-Mercator (3857). By right-clicking in QGIS on your layer you have a `Set CRS --> Set Layer CRS` option. Go in there and change it.

[image]

Now we can export the data to GEOJSON again. And this time make sure you select the WGS84 (4326). The resulting geojson (map.geojson) now looks like this:

[image]

Looking at the map this might be wrong. But now you have a tool to work your way to correct your data.

Comment: It looks like spherical mercator (3857). Also, four [ brackets doesn't seem right] unless it is a multipolygon?

Comment: @JohnPowell MultiPolygon are 4 bracketed.

Comment: Yes, I did say, unless it is a multipolygon. Hard to know since OP didn't post a very complete snippet, but, if geojson.io doesn't load it, there is likely to be something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys for review! I have update the question with more description also a Geojson file is attached

Comment: @Saurabh Hope it helped you!

Comment: yes it helps me Anton ! ..  now i have to move this layer to its actual position.  I have its boundaries in the vector layer.. can you give me some clue how to achieve it ?